# numpy meshgrid MemoryError on ungridded netCDF

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, netcdf

I have 2 different netCDF files: one "gridded", one "ungridded" (see examples below).

I'm trying on both to do a meshgrid as below :

```
dataset = Dataset(file_name)
data = dataset.variables['air_temp'][:]
lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]
print lats.shape
print lons.shape
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
print lons.shape
print lats.shape
```

Gridded: `lats` : 1-D array (720,) and `lons`: 1-D array (1440,)
 and returns after `meshgrid` a 2-D array (720,1440).

```
lats:
[-89.875 -89.625 -89.375 -89.125 -88.875 -88.625 -88.375 -88.125 -87.875
 -87.625 -87.375 -87.125 -86.875 -86.625 -86.375 -86.125 -85.875 -85.625
 ...
  85.625  85.875  86.125  86.375  86.625  86.875  87.125  87.375  87.625
  87.875  88.125  88.375  88.625  88.875  89.125  89.375  89.625  89.875]

lons:
[  1.25000000e-01   3.75000000e-01   6.25000000e-01 ...,   3.59375000e+02
   3.59625000e+02   3.59875000e+02]
```

Ungridded: `lats`: 2-D array (1080, 2048) and `lons` (1080, 2048) I would expect after `meshgrid` a 2-D array (1080, 2048) but it returns instead `MemoryError`

```
lats: 
[[-34.18847656 -34.20410156 -34.21972656 ..., -40.50195312 -40.50488281
  -40.5078125 ]
 [-34.19726562 -34.21289062 -34.22851562 ..., -40.51171875 -40.51367188
  -40.51660156]
 [-34.20605469 -34.22167969 -34.23828125 ..., -40.52246094 -40.52441406
  -40.52734375]
 ..., 
 [-43.77441406 -43.79394531 -43.81347656 ..., -50.73339844 -50.73339844
  -50.734375  ]
 [-43.78320312 -43.80175781 -43.82226562 ..., -50.7421875  -50.74316406
  -50.74316406]
 [-43.79199219 -43.81054688 -43.83105469 ..., -50.75195312 -50.75195312
  -50.75292969]]

lons:
[[  4.93164062   4.9765625    5.02148438 ...,  36.7734375   36.82421875
   36.875     ]
 [  4.92675781   4.97167969   5.015625   ...,  36.77246094  36.82324219
   36.87402344]
 [  4.921875     4.96679688   5.01171875 ...,  36.77148438  36.82226562
   36.87304688]
 ..., 
 [ -1.18457031  -1.13574219  -1.08691406 ...,  36.3359375   36.3984375
   36.45996094]
 [ -1.19238281  -1.14257812  -1.09375    ...,  36.3359375   36.3984375
   36.45996094]
 [ -1.19921875  -1.14941406  -1.09960938 ...,  36.3359375   36.3984375
   36.45996094]]
```

The `np.meshgrid` works perfectly on the gridded one: few ms with almost no RAM used, on the other hand  the gridded one completely crashes my Mac. I have to kill python process through the Activity Monitor. I thought it was because my computer has only 4GB of RAM but I tried with a friend running on Windows with 16GB and same issue.

I saw only one post talking about using smaller chunks of data but this netCDF file is only 2Mb! How can it generate 16Gb of RAM ?

The shape of the arrays of `lats` and `lons`of the "ungridded" one is due to the fact that the data comes from satellite measurement then the pixels are not perfect "squares".

Comment: I used double quotes because gridded and ungridded terms are not clear enough in my mind (new to SIG). To answer your question, on the "ungridded" netCDF, `lats` (and `lons`as well) is a 2-D array and its shape is (1080, 2048). If I do the exact same thing on the "gridded" one, `lats` will be a 1-D array (if it was the same dimension its shape would be (1080,) here.).

Comment: Sorry for the bad practice I will name them differently. So if I understand correctly I cannot use two 2-D arrays as inputs for a `np.meshgrid`? It is only to map two 1-D vectors (or N 1-D vectors) into a 2-D (N-D) array? I found an alternative of using cartopy library which worked with my two 2-D arrays as inputs for lat/lon. I'm looking now onto iris which seems to most of my needs.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) does. It simply constructs grids out of vectors of coordinates by repetition. I can't think of many situations where it would make sense to pass a >1D array as an input to `meshgrid`. It sounds to me like you are actually trying to *interpolate* some irregularly sampled data on a regular 2D grid, in which case something like [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) would be more appropriate.

Comment: I've edited my post so you can see the values of `lats`and`lons`. The difference between the two is that the "gridded one" is a rectangle, and the "ungridded" one is almost a rectangle but "curvy". The first file has been re-gridded already. My goal was to have a gridded mesh to use in Basemap like in [those examples](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) . As it's working on cartopy (and I guess iris) and both use numpy, what am I missing? I don't want to interpolate at this step as I will use iris' regridding functions.

Comment: If you don't want to interpolate then what *should* the output look like? If you want the output to be a rectangular array then you will need to fill in the missing values along the "curvy" edges with something (perhaps you could pad your array with NaNs, or use an `np.masked_array`). You'll have to be more specific. In any case, the reason for the memory error is definitely that you're passing large 2D arrays to `np.meshgrid` (the result for your "ungridded" data will be a pair of `(1080*2048, 1080*2048)` arrays, each of which would take up ~40TB of RAM assuming 64bit floats!).

Comment: Found out! I still didn't find why exactly but at some point `m.pcolormesh(lons,lats,data,shading='flat',cmap=plt.cm.jet,latlon=True)
` refused my 2-D inputs as above in the "ungridded" file. Then I thought it has to be a `np.meshgrid`of two 1-D inputs, not understanding that the point of this was to have two 2-D grids inputs, right? Everything seems to make sense now ! Anyway I will use iris & cartopy for the rest of my project as they seem to fit my needs. Thanks @ali_m